# I really don't know why my collectionViewCell disappear

Tags: swift, calendar, collectionview

I making a calendar so first I make a array like this [0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,...,31] by thing.optimize(month: 5). in this array, the reason I make 0 in front of 1,2,3,...,31 is 
when I make cell, I'm using an  `if` statement so `if cell.text == 0` then I set `cell.isHidden = true`. 
When I select the one cell I reload both of `collectionView(collectionView,nextMonthCollectionView)` and make round red shape.
When I select another button, a problem occurs, 
suddenly the cell disappears. I added a photo of this.

First, this is my code.

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nowMonthName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextMonthName: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextMonthCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var thing = realOptimaize()
    var selectedIndex : IndexPath?
    var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
    var forCollectionViewCount : Int?
    var monthData : Array<Int>?
    var nextMonthData : Array<Int>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
         monthData = thing.optimaize(month: 5)
         nextMonthData = thing.optimaize(month: 6)

        self.title = String(CalenderBrain.init().curruntYear)
        nowMonthName.text = String(CalenderBrain.init().curruntMonthName())
        nextMonthName.text = String(CalenderBrain.init().nextMonthName())

        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
        self.nextMonthCollectionView.dataSource = self
        self.nextMonthCollectionView.delegate = self

        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier : "MyCell")
        self.nextMonthCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "NextMonthCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell2")

        //이해가 잘 안가는 부분!!!
        if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = -0.2
        }
        if let layout2 = self.nextMonthCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
            layout2.minimumInteritemSpacing = -0.2
        }

    }

    }


    `extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,` UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if collectionView == self.nextMonthCollectionView {
            forCollectionViewCount = nextMonthData!.count
            return forCollectionViewCount!
        } else {
            forCollectionViewCount = monthData!.count
            return forCollectionViewCount!
        }
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { if collectionView == self.nextMonthCollectionView{
        let forCollectionViewCell = nextMonthCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell2", for: indexPath) as! NextMonthCollectionViewCell
//        forCollectionViewCell.button.tag = indexPath.item
        if nextMonthData![indexPath.row] == 0 {
            forCollectionViewCell.isHidden = true
        } else {
            forCollectionViewCell.Label.text = String(nextMonthData![indexPath.row])
            }
            return forCollectionViewCell
        } else {

        let forCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
//        forCollectionViewCell.button.tag = indexPath.item + 100
        if monthData![indexPath.row] == 0 {
            forCollectionViewCell.isHidden = true
        } else {
            forCollectionViewCell.Label.text = String(monthData![indexPath.row])
        }
        return forCollectionViewCell

        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if collectionView == nextMonthCollectionView {
            return .init(width: 53.25  , height: 67)
        } else{
            return .init(width: 53.25  , height: 67)
        }
    }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if collectionView == self.nextMonthCollectionView {
            let forCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! NextMonthCollectionViewCell
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
            collectionView.reloadData()
            forCollectionViewCell.Label.textColor = .white
            forCollectionViewCell.Label2.backgroundColor = .red
            forCollectionViewCell.Label2.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * forCollectionViewCell.Label2.bounds.size.width
            forCollectionViewCell.Label2.clipsToBounds = true
        }else{
            let forCollectionViewCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            self.nextMonthCollectionView.reloadData()
            collectionView.reloadData()
            forCollectionViewCell.Label.textColor = .white
            forCollectionViewCell.Label2.backgroundColor = .red
            forCollectionViewCell.Label2.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * forCollectionViewCell.Label2.bounds.size.width
            forCollectionViewCell.Label2.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my photo. this first photo is before I press any cell.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4TUL.png)

and this second photo is right after I press 13cell.
I really don't know why this happens.
I searched google looking for this information, but I didn't find an answer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeqDZ.png)

ps) when I don't use reloadData() function.. I did not get error.. but
I have to use reloadData.. because I have to clean my collectionView and then make a newly selected cell round red cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`if nextMonthData![indexPath.row] == 0 {
            forCollectionViewCell.isHidden = true
        } else {
            forCollectionViewCell.isHidden =false
            forCollectionViewCell.Label.text = String(nextMonthData![indexPath.row])
            }
            return forCollectionViewCell
    }
```

`

setting else condition that will solve your problem.
The reason behind it is when collection view dequeuing cell may be that cell is already hidden that's why its disappearing.

Comment: That's not going to work. It's only happening when he clicks on a cell.

Comment: I think your opinion really good.. but I'm not good at English so it will be really thanks if you say more easily.. I'm sorry

Comment: I have not tried it. I don't have XCode available atm. I'm fairly certain it has to do with the `collectionView(didSelectItemAt...)`  method. I think what's happening is that he's reloading the CollectionView then attempting to update his item. Rather than updating Item THEN reloading.

Comment: But, he's creating a new item each time which is a bit confusing to me since it's not passed by REF.

Comment: @xTwisteDx had similar kind of situation and I ended up solving by completing else condition.

Comment: before I use collectionView(didSelectItremAt...) function. I use button tag and comparing but same thing happen.. so I try collectionView(didSelectItremAt...) function.. but result is same..

Comment: but if I set forCollectionViewCell.isHidden = false, then in my calendar I can not disappear my 0 cell.. I have to disappear "0"cell.. because there are no 0 in calendar..I just use 0 cell in order to make exact start line..

Comment: wow your point is exact!! my cell no longer disappear.. but when I chose one cell, other cell become around red cell..

Comment: why don't  you saving your selectedIndex and then reloading your collection?

Comment: I got a very good idea from you.. I think there some mismatching if I use isHidden and reloadData() together.. so first I make isHidden clear and then use reloadData(). so I fix my all error I really appreciate you.!!